# How do I upgrade Eclipse Classic to Java EE?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I want to develop HTML5 websites. I have already installed Java for Android development. I have Eclipse Classic 3.6 installed on my machine. Now I wish to have Java EE on the same machine. Is it possible? If so, let me know how to upgrade Eclipse Classic 3.6 to the Java EE development environment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you need is **Web Tools Platform** added to your Eclipse installation. The info on how to accomplish this can be found [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F)

Comment: nope even after installing WTP via update i was not able to see dynamic website wizard

Comment: Dynamic Web Project Wizard is definitely part of WTP. Here is the proof in Eclipse documentation: 

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/ccwebprj.html

Notice that the article is part of 'Web Tools Platform User Guide'

Comment: i agree but i couldn't install that buddy. so i just download J2ee java and made android plug-in to that.

Comment: you could use [this](http://eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php) to compare your installation and then individually update

Answer (score 15):

Eclipse menu Help - "Install new software"
Then in the work with : "Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo" (or your eclipse version)

Then choose :
Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi ...
Then select: 
Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools

continue the update and I think that's it :-)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php)'s site the following packages are added to the Java EE edition:

- Data Tools Platform
- Java EE Developer Tools
- JavaScript Development Tools
- Maven Integration for Eclipse
- Mylyn Task List
- Remote System Explorer
- XML Editors and Tools

To add the packages:

1. Select ***Help*** > ***Install New Software***.
2. Under ***Work with*** select your eclipse's version name. (i.e.: Luna, Kepler, Juno, Indigo, Helios, etc.)
3. Filter by entering the first package's name where it says ***type filter text***.
4. Put a check mark next to the package.
5. Repeat for each package.
6. Select ***Next >*** to review the selected packages.
7. Select ***Next >*** to accept the selected packages.
8. Accept the terms of any licence agreements and click ***Finish***.

Answer (score -2):

Just download Eclipse for Java EE; merge your Eclipse classic folder with contents of downloaded archive. if you do this, you should be able to use in your Eclipse wth the features from Java EE version.

Comment: and that automatic is?