# Upgrade Eclipse neon to Java EE using ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, eclipse-neon

How can I upgrade my Eclipse neon to Java EE ( I need to create a java servelet that needs to be called by my php) using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install modules that are required for Java EE. Have a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849294/how-do-i-upgrade-eclipse-classic-to-java-ee) thread

Comment: Yup I tried that, sadly I am not getting the Java Web Development EE.

Comment: I had the same issue with the eclipse classic  that comes with Ubuntu. Please remove that and re-install the one that for J2ee